# Highcharts: multiple charts in the same pane with different Y axis?

Tags: highcharts

Here is an example of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/y9h46Le8/27/ where I have two series of data, referenced as `ohlc` and `volume`. I need them both displayed at one pane (as in example I provided) but they will need to have separate Y axises.

The data for `volume` series will always have values that are above the `ohlc` series and the `ohlc` series will not be visible because of this overlapping. In the example I provided, we can see how it's already overlapping for some points. Considering that in my data this will be the case for all points, that means my `ohlc` series will never be visible.

So what I wonder is, if there is a way where two different series will be placed on the same pane, but will have different range of Y axis?

This is just an example of one idea that I have: Since I need `ohlc` series to be in the main focus, maybe we can set min value of the `ohlc` series to always be above 30% of the pane and the max value of the current visible `volume` series can always be below the 30% of the pane. Something like limiting the min/max value of the series in the current pane:
[image]

I found something similar here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/A1cPrGLb-Example-Monte-Carlo-Simulation/ so that way will work as well. I wonder if this is feasible with highcharts?

Comment: Hi @delux, You can add another y-axis and play with `min` and `max` properties. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8xbqk0uc/ Did you want to do something like that?

Comment: @ppotaczek that's acceptable way of displaying the data for me. But there is one major issue: data which I provided is static data and data in my real project is dynamic data and it varies significantly. User will be able to zoom in/out, to scroll left/right, meaning that candles which are in the focus will be continually changed. So not sure how this approach will fit in my dynamic environment.

Comment: That can be problematic. You can try to dynamically set `min` and `max` value based on some pattern.

Comment: @ppotaczek and on which event do you suggest that I should update them? I guess I need to do on an event when the candles which are in the focus are changed (meaning that user zoomed in/out or he scrolled left/right).

Comment: I think that `render` event will be good., but you need to remember about infinity loop, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5aj1my38/